# TypeError: res.res.sent is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I don't know why I am getting this, I have tried many thing but nothing is working, my Express is installed and updated so I don't know what is causing this problem

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sentFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.post("/", function(req, res){
  var weight = Number(req.body.weight);
  var height = Number(req.body.hight);
  var height2 = (height * height);
  var bmi = weight/height;
  res.sent("your bmi is " + bmi);

});
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("server is live on port:3000");
}
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>bmi</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Enter your weight">
    <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="enter height">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">calculate</button>
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is package.json

```js
{
  "name": "my-express-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "muaaz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: `res.sent` -> `res.send`?

Comment: typo - `res.send`

Comment: Also, `sentFile` -> `sendFile`

Comment: ohh my god that was so obvious i aam sorry hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `res.sent` and `res.sentFile` to `res.send` and `res.sendFile`